# ssl v3 poodle and move to tls with indy

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

As you know the new [poodle](https://twitter.com/twittersecurity?original_referer=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.theregister.co.uk%2F2014%2F10%2F15%2Fpoodle_ssl3_twitter_cloudflare%2F&tw_i=522190947782643712&tw_p=tweetembed) is in town, Witch barks got [Twitter, Cloudflare](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/10/15/poodle_ssl3_twitter_cloudflare/) to drop support to SSL3.

The Indy(TidHttp) 10.6.0.0 revives this nice exception:

> EidOsslUnerlayingCryptoError message 'Error connecting with SSL.
>   error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake
>   failure'

My question is what is the definition required to handle TLS?

update:
here is a code that throw the exception: full working code.

```
var
  parameters:TStringList;
  keySecretBase64:string;
  stream:TStringStream;
  IdEncoderMIME1 : TIdEncoderMIME;
  idHttp1 : TIdHTTP;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1:TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;//assume on Form
begin
  stream:=TStringStream.create;
  parameters:=TStringList.Create;
  IdEncoderMIME1 := TIdEncoderMIME.Create(nil);
  idHttp1 := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1:=TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
    with IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 do begin
      SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
      SSLOptions.Mode :=  sslmUnassigned;
      SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
      SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 2;
    end;
    with idHttp1 do begin
      IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1;
      ReadTimeout := 0;
      AllowCookies := True;
      ProxyParams.BasicAuthentication := False;
      ProxyParams.ProxyPort := 0;
      Request.ContentLength := -1;
      Request.ContentRangeEnd := 0;
      Request.ContentRangeStart := 0;
      Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      Request.Accept := 'text/html, */*';

      Request.BasicAuthentication := False;
      Request.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/3.0 (compatible; Indy Library)';
      HTTPOptions := [hoForceEncodeParams];
    end;
    parameters.Clear;
    idHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
    IdEncoderMIME1.FillChar:='=';

  try
    keySecretBase64 := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(key+ ':' + secret, IndyTextEncoding_UTF8);// this is twitter provided key and secret
    parameters.Add('grant_type=client_credentials');
    idHttp1.Request.CustomHeaders.AddValue('Authorization','Basic '+keySecretBase64);
    idHttp1.post(URL,parameters,stream);
  finally
    stream.Free;
    parameters.Free;
    parameters.Free;
    IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You are connecting with TLSv1 only, so you can only connect to servers using the SSLv23 wildcard or TLSv1 specifically, otherwise your TLSv1 handshake will fail.

Comment: Your example code could be so much shorter - only `IdHttp.Get('https://www.google.com')` or a different https address and the SSLIOHandler part is required

Comment: true. however google does not deny ssl and force tls, as far as i know, check the second link about twitter and cloudflare.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am using Delphi 2007.  Where can I find a version of Indy10 that will be compatible with sslvTLSv1_2?  The version I get from http://indy.fulgan.com/zip/  is throwing "TIdTextEncoding undefined" errors.

Comment: @MSchenkel: The `TIdTextEncoding` class was replaced with a new `IIdTextEncoding` interface in Indy 10.6. See [this blog article](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/changeLog/20130423.EN.aspx).

Comment: @mjn: the code can be shortened even further if you take into account that `TIdHTTP` can now create its own `SSLIOHandler` (that defaults to TLSv1), if one has not already been assigned, when requesting an HTTPS url. See [this blog article](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/blogs/changeLog/20141222.EN.aspx).

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you Remy as always - I was able to get it going.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code selects `TLS 1.2` in the SSLOptions property `Method`:

```
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1.SSLOptions.SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1_2];
```

However, two lines later this value is overwritten with `SSL 3`:

```
with IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL1 do begin
  SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv3;
  ...
end;
```

So the client will not connect with the newer TLS 1.2 protocol but with SSL 3, which is no longer supported by the server.

This explains the error message, which says that the SSL 3 handshake (which the client tried) failed:

> SSL. error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake
>   failure'

If you remove the second assignment, the IdHTTP client will use TLS 1.2 for the connect.

Comment: you did progress the problem, however there is now a "Soket Error # 10054 connection reset by peer", which doesnt make the tls connection. reason code incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

SSL2, SSL3 and TLS1.0 are all vulnerable for man-in-th-middle attacks. You should use TLS 1.1 and upper for secure connection. Unfortunately, Indy 9 does not support TLS 1.1 and upper.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101816/how-to-make-indy-openssl-compatible-with-most-servers) reports that there is an option TLSv1_2 for TLS 1.2 in Indy 10, but it is not presented in Indy 10 [online documentation](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=TIdSSLVersion.html).